# How to Make Simple OpenGl C++ program using xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl

I want to make a very simple open gl program using xcode. all i want is a window with a black background. I also want to create some functions that can draw lines, images and other stuff on the screen. the reason i want to make this is because i created a program on windows in c++ and i just want to port it to mac. so i just want to create a simple window that lets me draw point and line?

Comment: Using GLUT will probably be the simplest way.

Answer (score 4):

Writing regular openGL code via Xcode is easy. (my Xcode version is 4.6.2)

1) create a new project whose template is `OSX -> Application -> Command Line Tool`.
[image]

in the next page, choose `c++` as the type for this project.

2) after creating the new project successfully, click `your project -> TARGETS -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`. Then add `GLUT.framework` and `OpenGL.framework`.[image]

3) you are ready to include the relative openGL headers in your code!
however, please notice that "GLUT" is "GL" on Windows. if you want to avoid cross platform issue, you can use the following pre-processor statement:

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else 
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

furthermore, for people who want to develop openGL application on Mac without using Xcode, you can reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525519/938380)

Answer (score 1):

Try the demo apps at the apple site, e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004501

Comment: Have you successfully made any apps on using XCode?  If not, start with something simple first, and work your way up to the OpenGL app.  If so, you'll need to post more information about what errors you're encountering to get any help here.  Here's a good starting sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010611

Comment: i have done many iphone apps but never a mac osx app. the error i get is it says that no scheme can be found to run the app