# What libraries must I include to access GLUT/OpenGL (Mac without XCode)?

Tags: c, macos, opengl, glut

The title gets at the heart of the issue, but the issue arose from this code I got from a tutorial at SpaceSimulator.net. I will post it for you here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>

typedef struct {
    float x,y,z;
} vertex_type;

typedef struct {
    int a,b,c;
} polygon_type;

#define MAX_POLYGONS 2000
polygon_type polygon[MAX_POLYGONS];

#define MAX_VERTICES 2000
vertex_type vertex[MAX_VERTICES];

typedef struct {
    vertex_type vertex[MAX_VERTICES];
    polygon_type polygon[MAX_POLYGONS];
} obj_type,*obj_type_ptr;

int screen_width, screen_height, filling;
GLfloat rotation_x_increment, rotation_y_increment, rotation_z_increment;
GLfloat rotation_x, rotation_y, rotation_z;

obj_type cube =
{
    {
        -10,-10, 10, //vertex v0
         10,-10, 10, //vertex v1
         10,-10,-10, //vertex v2
        -10,-10,-10, //vertex v3
        -10, 10, 10, //vertex v4
         10, 10, 10, //vertex v5
         10, 10,-10, //vertex v6
        -10, 10,-10  //vertex v7
    },
    {
        0, 1, 4, //polygon v0,v1,v4
        1, 5, 4, //polygon v1,v5,v4
        1, 2, 5, //polygon v1,v2,v5
        2, 6, 5, //polygon v2,v6,v5
        2, 3, 6, //polygon v2,v3,v6
        3, 7, 6, //polygon v3,v7,v6
        3, 0, 7, //polygon v3,v0,v7
        0, 4, 7, //polygon v0,v4,v7
        4, 5, 7, //polygon v4,v5,v7
        5, 6, 7, //polygon v5,v6,v7
        3, 2, 0, //polygon v3,v2,v0
        2, 1, 0, //polygon v2,v1,v0
    }
};


void init(void)
{
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0);
   glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
   glViewport(0,0,screen_width,screen_height);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)screen_width/(GLfloat)screen_height,1.0f,1000.0f);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
}

void resize(int width, int height)
{
   screen_width=width; 
   screen_height=height; 
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glViewport(0,0,screen_width,screen_height);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)screen_width/(GLfloat)screen_height,1.0f,1000.0f);
   glutPostRedisplay ();
}

void keyboard_s (int key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key)
   {
      case GLUT_KEY_UP:
         rotation_x_increment = rotation_x_increment +0.005;
      break;
      case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
         rotation_x_increment = rotation_x_increment -0.005;
      break;
      case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
         rotation_y_increment = rotation_y_increment +0.005;
      break;
      case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
         rotation_y_increment = rotation_y_increment -0.005;
      break;
   }
}

void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key)
   {
      case ' ':
         rotation_x_increment=0;
         rotation_y_increment=0;
         rotation_z_increment=0;
      break;
      case 'r': case 'R':
         if (filling==0)
         {
            glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
            filling=1;
         } 
         else 
         {
            glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
            filling=0;
         }
      break;
   }
}

void display(void)
{
   int l_index;
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-50);
   rotation_x = rotation_x + rotation_x_increment;
   rotation_y = rotation_y + rotation_y_increment;
   rotation_z = rotation_z + rotation_z_increment;
   if (rotation_x > 359) rotation_x = 0;
   if (rotation_y > 359) rotation_y = 0;
   if (rotation_z > 359) rotation_z = 0;
   glRotatef(rotation_x,1.0,0.0,0.0);
   glRotatef(rotation_y,0.0,1.0,0.0);
   glRotatef(rotation_z,0.0,0.0,1.0);
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   for (l_index=0;l_index<12;l_index++)
   {
      glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
      glVertex3f( cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].a ].x, cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].a ].y, cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].a ].z);
      glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
      glVertex3f( cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].b ].x, cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].b ].y, cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].b ].z);
      glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
      glVertex3f( cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].c ].x, cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].c ].y, cube.vertex[ cube.polygon[l_index].c ].z);
   }
   glEnd();
   glFlush();
   glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(screen_width,screen_height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("www.spacesimulator.net - 3d engine tutorials: Tutorial 2");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc (resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc (keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc (keyboard_s);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Okay, so this gives this error with g++:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_glClear", referenced from:
          display()    in ccUTBKlR.o
          resize(int, int)in ccUTBKlR.o
... tons more of the same-style errors for every gl/glut function ...
```

Side question: what stage of compilation is this? It is past syntax errors, but not fully compiled.

So I suspect that the libraries I am including are not correct, or that the Mac versions of the libraries are somehow different; although I doubt the latter because GLUT is supposed to be portable.

What libraries do I have to include to get these GLUT/OpenGL functions? I know I have to include 'the GLUT/OpenGL ones'; I am hoping for something a bit more specific.

Also, I really have a sore spot for moving away from C/C++ and to objective-C and XCode, so I hope that there is a solution that does not involve this switch.

Comment: It seems that this is error at linker stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the OpenGL Framework to the linker options. GLUT is not part of OpenGL and must be installed separately. Once installed, you can add the GLUT Framework as well.

Comment: GLUT does come with Mac OS X out of package as well as OpenGL. However, after investigating what you said further, I found that the frameworks can be added to the linker through the command line via "-framework OpenGL -framework GLUT". Finally, I can develop without XCode.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds noob. I'm facing the same issue. How can I go about adding this flag to a cmakelist.txt so that I can build it by "make"?

Answer (score 9):

I am late, but I want to save some efforts for people who have the same problem. Frankly, datenwolf's answer is not clear.

OpenGL and GLUT come with the OS and Xcode installations. The default paths would be `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework`.

you can include the header you need directly and compile your code on the command line with the following linker options:

```
gcc YOUR_CODE -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

btw, "GLUT" is "GL" on Windows. if you want to avoid cross platform issue, you can use the following pre-processor statement:

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else 
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Since this came up as the original of a recent duplicate: I would use the order `-framework GLUT -framework OpenGL`. You generally want to link libraries/frameworks in the order from higher level to lower level, so that symbols referenced in the higher level libraries can be resolved when the lower level library is processed by the linker.