# C++ mac eclipse library not found for -lglut

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, opengl, glut

I made a simple OpenGL test file in eclipse.
And every time I try to build the project I get this error:

> library not found for -lglut

I have a macbook pro 2013 OSX. I also followed a complete guide how to import the libraries(OpenGL and GLUT).
Here is the guide: http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/courses/fall2011/csc406/Handouts/Tutorials/OSX/OpenGL_Eclipse_Tutorial_OSX.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [What libraries must I include to access GLUT/OpenGL (Mac without XCode)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094260/what-libraries-must-i-include-to-access-glut-opengl-mac-without-xcode)

Comment: Right, as suggested in the answers there, GLUT is a framework on OS X, not a plain library. Use `-framework GLUT`. I think the order of options suggested in those answers is unfortunate, even though it probably works. `-framework GLUT -framework OpenGL` is the correct order. BTW, GLUT is marked as deprecated in OS X 10.9, and it's getting harder and harder to still use it. It also doesn't support recent OpenGL versions.